# Group all elements with same name with their IDs Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to group all elements with same name and find their IDs and `$push` them in a list.

I have a dataset like

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Refrigerator'
},
{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Refrigerator'
},
{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'TV'
},
{
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'TV'
}
```

Expected Ouput

```
{
    'equipment_name': 'Refrigerator',
    'equipment_id': [1, 2]
},
{
    'equipment_name': 'TV',
    'equipment_id': [3, 4]
}
```

What I've tried

```
{'$group': {'_id': '$_id', 'equipmne_name': '$name'}}
{'$project': {'name': {'$push': {'$expr': ['$name', '$name']}}}
```

And a few more aggregation techniques with `$cond`

Comment: In `"$group"` you need `"_id"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    {'$group': {'_id': {'key': '$name', 'value': '$_id'}}},
    {'$group': {'_id': '$_id.key', 'result': {'$push': {'$toString': '$$ROOT._id.value'}}}},
    {'$project': {'_id': 0, 'equipment_name': '$_id', 'equipment_id': '$result'}}
]
```